# Write unit test in swift package manager for API call

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, swift-package-manager, xctestcase

I am completely new to writing unit test cases.
This is my first one to write and I am confused.
I am creating one swift package manager where I have written one method which will accept

1. URL
2. HTTPMethod
3. Parameter

and I am using Alamofire as package dependancy over there, which will call API from passed URL and then response will be catch.

Following is the code,
`Framework.swift` file

```
public let APIFramework = APICore.default
let version = "1.0.0"
```

`FrameworkClass.swift` file code

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol APICoreDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didReceiveData(data: Data)
}

open class APICore {
    public static let `default` = APICore()
    public var delegate: APICoreDelegate?
    open func processApiCall( url : String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Dictionary<String, Any>)
    {
        AF.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let jsonData = response.value else {
                    return
                }
                self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: jsonData as! Data)
            case .failure: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to write unit test case for this method in `CDHFrameworkTests` class.

```
import XCTest
@testable import CDHFramework

final class CDHFrameworkTests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {

    }
    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct
        // results.
    }

    static var allTests = [
        ("testExample", testExample),
    ]
}
```

Can any one help me with one test case at least, so that I can study that and try to write the rest of them.
I have read a lot, but all the material is quite confusing to me.
Any help to write test cases for this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about googling "swift unit test network call"?

Comment: Aside: it is considered bad practice to force potentially unwanted dependencies on the consumers of your package. Unless you have a really compelling reason to use Alamofire instead of URLSession, you should consider getting rid of this baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really good you're getting to know unit tests (they'll make your life SOOOO much easier, trust me).

A few things I must mention about your snippet of code above, since you're calling *Alamofire* directly in your API core class (`AF.request`) you won't be able to mock your network and hence not being able to perform a unit test per se. Sure, you could either:

- Use an HTTP proxy for your project to interact with and hence make your test reliable but that would introduce a whole lot of boilerplate and set up.
- Interact directly with a test/mock endpoint but this also comes with a caveat since you'd be relying on your network connection and having the need to introduce a bunch of waiting time in order to be able to sync your tests with the response times. **Not recommendable**.

You should check these resources out:

- [Unit testing your network layer](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-complete-guide-to-network-unit-testing-in-swift-db8b3ee2c327)
- [My own network library in SPM](https://github.com/mchirino89/MauriNet)

I need to improve the documentation on my library but the network layer is fully covered in tests + it's SPM (after all that was your original question).

I wish you all the best of lucks with automated testing in general, cheers!

PS: You should consider dismiss network layer dependencies for simple tasks. Libraries such as Alamofire and Moya are great choices if you need to do some *really* heavy lifting on the network side, otherwise they are unnecessary boilerplate. Check out these other great resources if you need a starting point:

- [Networking In Swift With URLSession](https://learnappmaking.com/urlsession-swift-networking-how-to/): nice intro to dip your toe in Swift's native `URLSession` waters
- [Network Requests and REST APIs in iOS with Swift (Protocol-Oriented Approach)](https://matteomanferdini.com/network-requests-rest-apis-ios-swift/): more advance stuff if you already are familiar with protocols and generics.